# If $H^2 = H^3$ and H is self-adjoint, prove that H is a projection matrix

Tags: hilbert-spaces, projection-matrices

I want to prove the following statement:

> Let $H$ be a self-adjoint operator in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Suppose that $H^2 = H^3$. Prove that $H = H^2$.

I tried to prove that proposition and I couldn't.

It seems to be very easy but I think that I need some trick to prove that proposition that I haven't noticed.

I need help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $H$ is self adjoint, note that $$\left<H^2x-Hx,H^2x-Hx\right>=\left<H^2x,H^2x\right>-\left<Hx,H^2x\right>-\left<H^2x,Hx\right>+\left<Hx,Hx\right>\\=\left<H^4x,x\right>-\left<2H^3x,x\right>+\left<H^2x,x\right>=\left<(H^4-2H^3+H^2)x,x\right>.$$ But, $H^3=H^2$, so $H^4=H^3$, therefore $H^4-2H^3+H^2=0$, showing that $$\left<H^2x-Hx,H^2x-Hx\right>=0$$ for all $x$. So, $H^2x=Hx$ for all $x$, therefore $H^2=H$.

Comment: In fact, $\langle (H^2-H)x, (H^2-H) x \rangle = \langle (H^3-H^2)x, (H-I) x \rangle = 0$.

Comment: Right, this is simpler.

Comment: But inspired by your answer :-). Always easier to follow than to lead.

Answer (score 1):

A proof using spectral theory in the case where $\mathcal{H}$ is complex:

Observe that if $T$ a self adjoint operator on $\mathcal{H}$, then $T$ is bounded (Hellinger- Toeplitz) and for the spectral radius $r(T)$ of $T$ we have

$$ r(T)=||T||.$$

Let us denote the spectrum of $T$ by $ \sigma(T)$

If $H$ is self adjoint, then the operators $H^2-H$ and $H^3-H^2$ are also self adjoint.

Now let $\lambda \in \sigma(H^2-H)$. The spectral mapping theorem gives that there is $\mu \in \sigma(H)$ such that $\lambda=\mu^2- \mu$.

We get (use again the spectral mapping theorem)

$$ \lambda \mu=\mu^3-\mu^2 \in \sigma(H^3-H^2)=\sigma(0)=\{0\}.$$

Thus $ \lambda \mu =0$. Together with $\lambda=\mu^2- \mu$ we derive that $\lambda=0$. Therefore we have

$$ \sigma(H^2-H)=\{0\},$$

hence $||H^2-H||=r(H^2-H)=0$, which gives $H^2=H$.